# Grandfather and Grandson

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle

My Puzzle is as follows-

> Once, I said to my friend that, "In 1932 I was as old as the last two digits of my birth year. When I mentioned this interesting coincidence to my grandfather, he surprised me by saying that the same applied to him too. I thought that impossible...." 
> "Of course that's impossible," my friend said. 
> "Believe me, it's quite possible and grandfather proved it too. How old was each of us in 1932?"

What is my and my grandfather's age?

[Source](https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Mathematics_Can_Be_Fun.html?id=P5wAOwAACAAJ&source=kp_book_description&redir_esc=y)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you were

> 16 years old, born 1916

And your grandfather was

> 66 years old, born 1866

Note:

> This seems to simple, maybe i've missed something..